# Loading Google Maps to C# Winform without web browser

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to integrate Google Maps into a C# WinForms application without embedding a browser into the application?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in 2016, Google declared that you must use a key to use their Google Maps API, that leaves you with 2 options.

1. To open Google Maps from the internet directly by URL (using a browser) or
2. Get a key, and run it using javascript, but you'd still need a browser to execute the javascript.

As far as I know, there are no current option to use Google's API offline from your own application, even the offline version of Google Maps itself will only be available for 30 days, due to the daily change in infrastructure in the world.